# Cola Machine #1

Tags: c++, io

I have been working on the code listed [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/).
I am working on Problem #2, 0 stars. Here's what I have to do:

> Write a program that presents the user w/ a choice of your 5 favorite beverages (Coke, Water, Sprite, ... , Whatever).
>   Then allow the user to choose a beverage by entering a number 1-5.
>   Output which beverage they chose.

**NOTE:**
I won't be creating a switch statement or making a error message if you give a value other than one that is 1-5, because that are part of the next step in the project.

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    int UserSodaChoice;

    cout << "Cola Machine V1" << endl;
    cout << "1. Coca-Cola" << endl;
    cout << "2. Sprite" << endl;
    cout << "3. Fanta" << endl;
    cout << "4. Mountain Dew" << endl;
    cout << "5. Pepsi" << endl;
    cout << "Pick your favorite beverage: ";
    cin >> UserSodaChoice;

    if (UserSodaChoice == 1)
    {
        cout << "I don't like Coca-Cola...";
    }
    if (UserSodaChoice == 2)
    {
        cout << "Sprite is ok I guess.";
    }
    if (UserSodaChoice == 3)
    {
        cout << "Waayyyy too much sugar.";
    }
    if (UserSodaChoice == 4)
    {
        cout << "Mountain Dew! Nice.";
    }
    if (UserSodaChoice == 5)
    {
        cout << "Eww. People don't drink Pepsi these days, it ain't the 90's.";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t";
}
```

Comment: This is minor enough not to warrant being an answer, but: convention dictates that variables use `camelCase` or `snake_case`, while `PascalCase` is reserved for type definitions (classes, etc.).

Comment: @Schism really? Our professor told us to use the Hungarian Case Method for EVERYTHING.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Hungarian Convention is something entirely different -- it's the practice of prefixing variable names with a string indicating its type. (Examples: `strHelloWorld`, `bIsRaining`, `btnCancel`, `$this`)

Comment: @Schism -_- Just another thing to add to the list of "put on professor's desk anonymously  after we get our grades in". Okay, then what typing convention is it?

Comment: By convention, I meant your naming; since `UserSodaChoice` is a variable rather than a class or a struct, it should be `userSodaChoice` or similar instead. (You'll notice that the highlighting here will even change!)

Comment: @Schism I understand, but is there a specific naming convention for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good for you, avoiding `using namespace std;`.

Within the constraints you requested (i.e. no `switch` block, no error handling), there's not that much to review.

Avoid excessive use of `endl`, as that flushes the output unnecessarily.  You could write the menu as one long constant.  (String literals placed immediately after each other will be treated as one.) <s>Flush it just once at the end, using `std::flush`.</s> As @LokiAstari points out, you don't need to explicitly flush at all; reading from `cin` will automatically cause a flush of `cout`.

```
cout << "Cola Machine V1\n"
        "1. Coca-Cola\n"
        "2. Sprite\n"
        "3. Fanta\n"
        "4. Mountain Dew\n"
        "5. Pepsi\n"
        "Pick your favorite beverage: ";
```

Comment: Flush the output?

Comment: What do you mean by flushing the output?

Comment: @piperchester Since writing to the screen involves operating system-level code, which has high overhead, it's more efficient to do so in larger batches. Therefore, writing to `cout` actually puts characters into a buffer. Sometimes the buffer contents are automatically transferred to screen, in a process known as "flushing". You can also force a flush to happen wherever you need to ensure that the user sees everything you have tried to write so far.

Comment: No point in flushing std::cout. When ever you read from std::cin the std::cout is automatically flushed. There is very little reason to ever force a flush.

Comment: @LokiAstari one reason is that then you can modify the code, move the cin around, and not have to worry about a hanging cout. Also, it makes your intentions explicit.

Comment: @Davidmh: OK. I can buy that. (making intentions explicit). But cout is not going to hang in any way that will affect your code.

Comment: @LokiAstari I meant "hanging" as "left alone and uncared for". So you could have displayed just a fragment of the output.

Comment: Isn't `cout` also flushed when a `\n` is written? That's the case in libc, anyway. And that reeks of a micro-optimization, rather than anything useful for learning to code.

Comment: The comment "Good for you, avoiding using namespace std;" doesn't really make sense. If you look at the OP code, then obviously either 'using namespace std' or else 'using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;' must appear in the program (but was probably not shown for brevity). BTW there is absolutely *nothing wrong* with 'using', despite what people around SO like to say. If you like to prefix 'std::' with everything under the sun, be my guest. But if I don't like to, I use 'using'.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another way of performing the dispatch according to a user selection would be with an array of strings. Or better still, with an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), assuming your compiler is C++11 capable (which is probably the case):

```
// Add these somewhere:
#include <array>
#include <string>

...

const std::array<std::string, 5> choices = {
    "I don't like Coca-Cola...",
    "Sprite is ok I guess.",
    "Waayyyy too much sugar.",
    "Mountain Dew! Nice.",
    "Eww. People don't drink Pepsi these days, it ain't the 90's."
};

if (UserSodaChoice >= 1 && UserSodaChoice <= choices.size())
{
    cout << choices[UserSodaChoice - 1];
}
// Else, handle invalid input...
```

Notice the `- 1` when indexing the array. This is because `UserSodaChoice` ranges from 1 to 5, while the array range is 0 to N-1.

Comment: Wouldn't a `str::string[5]` achieve the same? (I don't know C++).

Comment: @Mephy - Yes, absolutely. I suggested `std::array` just to make some advertisement of the new library `;)`. It has some advantages over a raw array though. One of the nicest things is that `std::array` knows its length, something that a `string[]` would lack (you would have to keep some external constant or variable with the length, or remember it in your head). There are other benefits to it too. Take a look at the link I've provided, it has a few examples.

Comment: `std::array<>` is fine. Personally I would have preferred `std::vector<>` as there is no magic numbers involved (5). I would probably have used `UserSodaChoice <= choices.size()` as now adding an element to the array means three edits to the code.

Comment: @LokiAstari - You are right, `UserSodaChoice <= choices.size()` would be more adequate. I should change that. As for the `vector`, I think you said yourself in a review somewhere not to use a dynamic allocation where a static will do. If the OP wants to upgrade to a `vector` in the future, the transition with `array` is seamless. No need to pay for the dynamic allocation if you don't need one.

Comment: Pay is a rather loaded word. Here the cost is one allocation for the life of the object. But in real life I would not reject this in a code review. So its fine. I just wanted to state my preference for an vector.

Comment: @LokiAstari - No prob. Your point about having to use a constant for the array size is also legit. I wish the compiler could infer the size just as it would with a common C-style array `;)`.

Answer (score 12):

I would build a closely-coupled mapping between the item and the message, which makes it easier to add, remove, and reorder items without things going screwy.  For a really simple example:

```
struct Beverage {
    const std::string name;
    const std::string message;
    Beverage(const std::string& name, const std::string& message):
        name(name),
        message(message)
    {}
};

int main() {
    Beverage choices[5] = {
        Beverage("Coca-Cola", "I don't like Coke"),
        Beverage("Sprite", "Too much sugar"),
        // ...
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ": " << choices[i].name << std::endl;
    }

    int selected;
    std::cin >> selected;
    if (selected >= 1 && selected <= 5) {
        std::cout << choices[selected - 1].message << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid choice" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this is not the overall program structure, but an example of how to make a closer coupling between the choices and responses.

Answer (score 10):

Just something minor:

I would suggest using a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if` statements.

```
switch(UserSodaChoice){

case 1:
    cout << "I don't like Coca-Cola...";
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Sprite is ok I guess.";
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "Waayyyy too much sugar.";
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Mountain Dew! Nice.";
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "Eww. People don't drink Pepsi these days, it ain't the 90's.";
    break;
default:
    cout << "Error.\n";
    break;
}
cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t";
```

> NOTE: I won't be creating a switch statement or making a error
>   message...

Oops, sorry. For some reason I did not see this. I guess that would make my review useless to you, but I don't think it is completely moot.

Comment: Using `if()else` or `switch` is usually a mistake. There is usually a better data driven solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++11

```
// some includes you can figure out
...
// good choice for adding to the global name space.
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

// Use predefined data structures (STL) when possible
// they are usually less error prone and sometimes faster.
using Products = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

// Don't use magic numbers like 5 or use some const to describe them.
// Use resizeable arrays like vector unless the size is set in stone, which
// vending machines aren't, adding Coke-Lite gives fewer problems this way.
std::vector<Products> brands {
    { "Coca-Cola", "I don't like Coca-Cola..." },
    { "Sprite", "Sprite is ok I guess." },
    { "Fanta", "Waayyyy too much sugar." },
    { "Mountain Dew", "Mountain Dew! Nice." },
    { "Pepsi", "Eww. People don't drink Pepsi these days, it ain't the 90's." }
};

void DisplayMenu() {
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Cola Machine V1" << "\n";
    for(auto prod: brands)
        cout << ++count << ". " << prod.first << "\n";

    cout << "Pick your favorite beverage: ";
}

int Vending() {
    // always initialize your variables,
    // even if you ATM can see they don't need it
    int UserSodaChoice = 0;

    DisplayMenu();  // reduce code clutter by using functions

    cin >> UserSodaChoice;

    // ToDo in V2 validate UserSodaChoice
    auto prod = brands[UserSodaChoice-1];
    cout << prod.first << ": " << prod.second << endl;

    return UserSodaChoice;
}

int main() {
    return Vending(); // do something fantastic with the return value
}
```

If you are learning to use classes later then you can easily transform it into a class as the structure is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Flush your output..  And use if else... Instead of using just and if statement..  Using if else.. Reduces the execution time of your program... 
NOTE: using a structure further simplifies your program.

Also use a do while loop..

```
do
{ 
    //Print ur menu... 
    //Ask the user if he wants to select again..
}
while ( condition)
```

This will make the program look professional.. Also include a clear screen (`clrscr()`) within the do while..

Comment: I've edited your post; you can make code blocks appear by indenting code by 4 spaces. You can also inline code with backticks ```. When you edit you should see edit and formatting help to your right.

Comment: Since when is using a do-while going to make your program look professional?